# Is the polynomial $x^2-xy^5-y^2-1$ an irreducible polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Fix a field $k$ of characteristic $0$, and let $f=x^2-xy^5-y^2-1\in k[x,y]$. I've succeeded in proving that $f$ is nonsingular at each point, but I'm struggling to prove irreducibility. Is there any useful criterion here?

Comment: In a factorization, what degree with respect to x can the factors have?

Comment: I see your point, and I've reduced to showing that $y^10+4y^2+4\in k[y]$ is not a square. But I don't see why this is obvious.

Comment: So, I showed that using the Euclidean algorithm. The same can be done for $y$. Now what?

Comment: Why would you do it also for $y$? Why woud anything be obvious? I have no idea what you meant :-/

Comment: If you write your polynomial al $f(x,y)g(x,y)$, the degree of $f$ with respect to $x$ plus the degree of $g$ with respect to $x$ has to be exactly $2$, so either one of them does not depend on $y$ or both of them are linear with respect to $x$. Use that to deduce what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Gauss's Lemma, it suffices to prove that $f$ is irreducible in $k(y)[x]$.  As you indicate in the comments, since $f$ has degree $2$ in $x$, then $f$ is reducible iff it has a root, which by the quadratic formula (here we need that the characteristic of $k$ is not $2$) occurs iff the discriminant $g := y^{10} + 4y^2 + 4$ is a square.  One can show that $\gcd(g, g') = 1$ using the Euclidean algorithm, which implies that $g$ is squarefree, hence is not a square.