# Is the ring $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(f)$ an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

From Artin algebra chapter 13, Question 5.3

Let $f = y^2 - x ^3 - x$.Is the ring $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(f)$ an integral domain?

My works:   i know that if   $(f)$ is irreducible  then f will be maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(f)$  then the ring $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(f)$ an integral domain.

But here  how can i know that whether  $f$ is irreducible or not ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: $y^2 = x^3+x$ looks like an elliptic curve.

Comment: *Hint*: Consider $y^2 - x^3 - x \in \mathbb{C}[x][y]$, i.e., as a polynomial in $y$, and apply Eisenstein's criterion with the prime $x$. Alternatively, you use the argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244352/is-the-polynomial-x2-xy5-y2-1-an-irreducible-polynomial/2244614#2244614).

Comment: @André3000..thnaks u